# React creating JSX from state showing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

In my react application, on page load, I am calling an API and storing that value in the state. When I try to create a JSX element from the state I am getting the error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'expire')`.

```
const [domains, setDomains] = useState([]);
const [records, setRecords] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('zones/domains').then((res) => {
            setDomains(res.data)
            axios.get('zones/records', {
                params: {
                    l_id: res.data[0].l_id
                }
            }).then((res) => {
                setRecords(res.data)
            });
        });
        
    }, [])


let table_str = <tr>
    <td>SOA</td>
    <td>{records.added.expire}</td>
    <td>{records.added.value1} {records.added.value2}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `useState({});` The initial value you've chosen is an empty object. As such, `records.added` is undefined, and `records.added.expire` throws an error. Either change the initial value to have all the properties you need it to have, or check for the empty object before you try to access it's properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your states are empty before the axios call. Make sure to update as follows with optional changing.

```
let table_str = <tr>
    <td>SOA</td>
    <td>{records?.added?.expire}</td>
    <td>{records?.added?.value1} {records?.added?.value2}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: That will work, but if records is empty you might not want to display a table row at all.

Comment: True, but at least it doesn't throw an error.